# Does WHERE clause work with date comparision in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Below is a sample code for select with respect to date

**Code**

```
SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE date >='2017-06-01' AND date <='2017-06-33'
```

Will comparing date like this work or not?

instead of that string i will be supplying variables from PHP.

edit:

```
    SELECT * FROM account WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-33'
```

tried this alternative method by Ramraider too and its still not working.
Can we perform this kind of SQL query with dates.

Comment: Why do you ask instead of test on your own? If the fields are `date` or `datetime` or `timestamp` then yes, it will work.

Comment: Why don't you try & see by yourself?

Comment: you could alternatively use the `between` operator

Comment: I don't know of a 33rd day in a month, so no it won't work. `AND date <='2017-06-33'` if that's your real code that is.

Comment: i tried it. but it but didnt return anything even though date had a value of 2017-06-20... . And 33 day is just so that a whole month of 06 is covered .and thanks for the fast replies.

Comment: What type of field is date?

Comment: its a date field

Comment: Your queries are fine provided that you're using correct data types as mentioned. Just use `'2017-06-30'` instead of `'2017-06-33'`

Comment: Fred -ii-  sorry and u were right. thanks prabhat G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query:

```
SELECT * FROM account WHERE `date` BETWEEN
CAST('2017-06-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2017-06-30' AS DATE);
```

date is inbuilt data-type in mysql. So I am also wondering that you have kept your column-name inside account table as date ?

Moreover you can't mention 33. It has to be within `valid date range for the particular month`, 1 to 30 for June.

Comment: So the main problem lies in the date range .Thanks you were a big help.